# Kotlin Coroutines lockup/freezing

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I experience strange lockups (freezes) when running coroutines. Sometimes it works perfectly fine, sometimes it will just wait and continue running after a long time (or not at all). I don't know If my setup is incorrect, there is some race condition or maybe I misunderstand how coroutines are supposed to be used. The app itself doesn't freeze or crash, it's just the coroutines stop/pause execution.

For example, in this bit the `scope.launch` would sometimes just not continue executing into `billingClientDeferred.await()`

```
    override suspend fun getPurchases(): Result<List<Purchase>> = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    scope.launch {
        billingClientDeferred.await().success { client ->
            client.queryPurchasesAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS) Subs@{ billingResultSubs, purchasesSubs ->
                if (billingResultSubs.responseCode != BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    continuation.resume(Result.Failure.Unknown())
                    return@Subs
                }
                continuation.resume(Result.Success(purchasesSubs))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`scope` is declared as:

```
private val scope = CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.Default)
```

Then it is called from `WalletManager`

```
override suspend fun verifyProducts(): Result<Unit> = billingProvider.getPurchases()
        .successSuspend { purchases ->
            purchases.forEach {
                activatePurchase(it)
            }
        }.map { }
```

Which in the end is called from a `ViewModel` like  this

```
override fun verify() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        userSupervisor.walletManager.mapResult {
            it.verifyProducts()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm guessing there is some issue with the combination of what dispatchers and scopes I'm using. I was trying different things with `Dispatchers.Default`, `Dispatchers.Main`, conforming class to `CoroutineScope`, using global scopes, but I always run into some threading/lockup issues I don't fully understand.

Comment: what exactly is your reasoning behind launching a new coroutine inside suspendCoroutine, do you clearly understand the use case of suspendCoroutine function?

Comment: Because I'm using both a callback based function `client.queryPurchasesAsync` and a coroutine based `billingClientDeferred.await()` inside. I could extract `queryPurchasesAsync` converting it into suspending function, and then wouldn't need to use `scope.launch` inside of `getPurchases`.

Is it a bad practice to do it like this? Could it be a cause of my issue?

Comment: It is a bad practice as your coroutines are no longer related in parent-child relationship. You have your root coroutine fired using viewModelScope and inside that coroutine you have another one fired using scope you defined. unless you're canceling that scope on your own, when viewModelScope is cancelled it will not cancel the coroutine fired using your scope. suspendCoroutine is bridging callback-based code and coroutine-based code. Convert whatever needs to be converted to avoid firing a new coroutine inside suspendCoroutine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First issue is that you don't want to launch a new coroutine from within the `suspendCoroutine`, you need to restructure your code so that you don't have to do this. this could be done as

```
private fun someMethod() = viewModelScope.launch {
    val client = billingClientDeferred.await()
    val finalResult = getPurchases(client)
}
```

after this simply update `getPurchases` to except the client as a parameter and remove all the coroutine code from it, just call the client and return the result using continuation.

### Fundamental issue with your code is that you are not following principle of [`structured concurrency`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#structured-concurrency).

its essentially a concurrency management pattern that implicitly takes care of the scope and lifetime of a coroutine. the idea is that when you launch coroutines using differnt scopes, those scopes must have  a parent child relationship, this allows the coroutine management system to take care of all the cases such as

1. What happens when an inner coroutine throws exception
2. What happens when an outer coroutine is canceled or failed

I am afraid your code doesn't really follow this pattern and has following issues

### `scope` doesn't have any relation with the `CoroutineScope` that launches `getPurchases`

This is a big problem, what happens if outer scope gets canceled, will it cancel the inner coroutine or the inner coroutine will keep consuming resources?

### You are launching a coroutine from a suspending function

As Roman Elizarov explains [here](https://elizarov.medium.com/coroutine-context-and-scope-c8b255d59055)

> Suspending functions, on the other hand, are designed to be
> non-blocking and should not have side-effects of launching any
> concurrent work. Suspending functions can and should wait for all
> their work to complete before returning to the caller.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think I understand it better now. In short, there should be no `launch` from within a `launch`.

Comment: What about `async`? I'm guessing it is fine since it's connected to the outer coroutine through `await`, so the same issue won't happen. Is using additional scope like this correct? `private val billingClientDeferred = scope.async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) { billingClient() }`

Comment: @Rafal I'd suggest you to thoroughly read the documentation for coroutines. There can be coroutines fired inside other coroutines, but nested coroutines should be child coroutines of the outer coroutines. This is the default behavior. It can be broken by either a) providing nested coroutines with another Job instance b) launching nested coroutines using different scope than the scope of the outer coroutines (this is what you have done, outer coroutine is fired using viewModelScope and the nested one using the scope you defined).